# acer vn7-591g BIOS password unlock reset

Tags: laptop, bios, acer-aspire

set BIOS password some time ago. When I tried to enter BIOS again yesterday it wouldn't accept my password. I couldn't have typed it wrong because the password is "a".
Disassembled it and removed the battery (small and large) for 6 hours, also pushed the power button while battery removed but it still asks for a password. Now it doesn't boot at all, says "no bootable device" although both the M2 SSD and the normal SSD are in place, connected to the motherboard.

My open options are:

- take laptop into acer service and wait...
- if I knew the system unlock password... the online tools which generate such password don't work
- find the bios/cmos jumper and reset it but don't know where they are because there is no service manual for download
- can't post to acer community forum because the text input field simply doesn't load (congrats acer)
- can't register my product because after entering the serial number it throws error (congrats acer)

any ideas? TIA!

Comment: You can't reset or clear a BIOS password in modern computers by resetting or clearing bios, it is stored in a security chip that cannot be cleared by the user, not part of the regular bios. Your options are send it in, take it to an Acer authorized service center, or use a 3rd party bios password reset tool (if one exists for your device).

Answer (score 0):

At the end I took it in a local laptop service shop and they cleared the BIOS pwd for me. After that I was also able to make dualboot ubuntu - windows 8.1 in bIOS/legacy mode.

Comment: Oh, so it shows again how secure those passwords are...